# pandas – apply function to DataFrame row-wise, resulting in a new DataFrame of different dimensions

Tags: python, pandas

I want to be able to apply a function to a `DataFrame` (row-wise) such that it can return a new `DataFrame` that does not necessarily have the same dimensions or indexing as the original.

Let's say I have a `DataFrame`, `df`:

```
    A   B   C   D
0  A0  B0  C0  D0
1  A1  B1  C1  D1
2  A2  B2  C2  D2
3  A3  B3  C3  D3
```

and a function `foo()`:

```
>>> def foo(series):
...  series['E'] = 'NEW_STUFF'
...  series['F'] = 'MORE_NEW_STUFF'
...  df = pd.DataFrame(series.drop('B')).transpose()
...  return pd.concat([df,df], keys='qw')
...
```

such that

```
>>> foo(df.iloc[0])
      A   C   D          E               F
q 0  A0  C0  D0  NEW_STUFF  MORE_NEW_STUFF
w 0  A0  C0  D0  NEW_STUFF  MORE_NEW_STUFF
```

I want to apply `foo()` to `df` such that it results in a new `DataFrame` where the results of running `foo()` on each row are stacked into a single `DataFrame`, kind of like

```
      A   C   D          E               F
q 0  A0  C0  D0  NEW_STUFF  MORE_NEW_STUFF
w 0  A0  C0  D0  NEW_STUFF  MORE_NEW_STUFF
q 1  A1  C1  D1  NEW_STUFF  MORE_NEW_STUFF
w 1  A1  C1  D1  NEW_STUFF  MORE_NEW_STUFF
q 2  A2  C2  D2  NEW_STUFF  MORE_NEW_STUFF
w 2  A2  C2  D2  NEW_STUFF  MORE_NEW_STUFF
q 3  A3  C3  D3  NEW_STUFF  MORE_NEW_STUFF
w 3  A3  C3  D3  NEW_STUFF  MORE_NEW_STUFF
```

However, running `df.apply(foo, axis=1)` does not return this. Instead I get

```
>>> df.apply(foo, axis=1)
0          A   C   D          E               F
q 0...
1          A   C   D          E               F
q 1...
2          A   C   D          E               F
q 2...
3          A   C   D          E               F
q 3...
dtype: object
```

What do I need to modify above to get the results I'm looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with

```
pd.concat([foo(y) for _,y in df.iterrows()])
Out[64]: 
      A   C   D          E               F
q 0  A0  C0  D0  NEW_STUFF  MORE_NEW_STUFF
w 0  A0  C0  D0  NEW_STUFF  MORE_NEW_STUFF
q 1  A1  C1  D1  NEW_STUFF  MORE_NEW_STUFF
w 1  A1  C1  D1  NEW_STUFF  MORE_NEW_STUFF
q 2  A2  C2  D2  NEW_STUFF  MORE_NEW_STUFF
w 2  A2  C2  D2  NEW_STUFF  MORE_NEW_STUFF
q 3  A3  C3  D3  NEW_STUFF  MORE_NEW_STUFF
w 3  A3  C3  D3  NEW_STUFF  MORE_NEW_STUFF
```